# PHPMyAdmin not working as intended at remote server. Error 500, $respond not found

Tags: php, symfony, server, phpmyadmin, apache2

I am just starting my journey with servers so I bought one VPN.
I installed there **ubuntu 18, apache 2.4, php8, webmin, mysql** etc.
I have two sites based on **symfony 5** hosted here without any problems.
I installed **PHPmyAdmin** using Ubuntu PPA: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/wiki/DebianUbuntu#ubuntu-ppa

When I go to *mysite.com/phpmyadmin* everything is fine. I log in with credentials and I am logged in. It reads databases properly and renders all UI as it should, but then it throws error 500
[Screenshot of PHPmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTqq3.png)

And it throws error in apache logs:

```
[Sun Oct 10 13:00:44.298896 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 30370:tid 140207772845824] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unknown named parameter $$response in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1140\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(1140): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs()\n#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(604): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder->createService()\n#2 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(569): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder->doGet()\n#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Routing.php(186): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder->get()\n#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(18): PhpMyAdmin\\Routing::callControllerForRoute()\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 1140'
[Sun Oct 10 13:00:44.359963 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 30369:tid 140207873558272] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unknown named parameter $$response in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1140\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(1140): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs()\n#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(604): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder->createService()\n#2 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(569): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder->doGet()\n#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Routing.php(186): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder->get()\n#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(18): PhpMyAdmin\\Routing::callControllerForRoute()\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 1140'
[Sun Oct 10 13:00:44.411282 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 30370:tid 140207898736384]  AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unknown named parameter $$response in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1140\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(1140): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs()\n#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(604): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder->createService()\n#2 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(569): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder->doGet()\n#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Routing.php(186): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder->get()\n#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(18): PhpMyAdmin\\Routing::callControllerForRoute()\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 1140'
[Sun Oct 10 13:14:58.028291 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 30369:tid 140207798023936]  AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unknown named parameter $$response in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1140\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(1140): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs()\n#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(604): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder->createService()\n#2 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php(569): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder->doGet()\n#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Routing.php(186): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerBuilder->get()\n#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(18): PhpMyAdmin\\Routing::callControllerForRoute()\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 1140'
```

I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @nakashu I found solution.

According to symfony issue he linked:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/8e34978e4e2c4bf7dac97e44e904368c4cfb54f8

I know it is only temporal solution but I replaced code in **/usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1140**

I changed:

`$service = null === $r->getConstructor() ? $r->newInstance() : $r->newInstanceArgs($arguments);`

to:

`$service = null === $r->getConstructor() ? $r->newInstance() : $r->newInstanceArgs(array_values($arguments));`

Now **phpMyAdmin** is working.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug / incompatibility in one of phpmyadmin dependencies - symfony dependency injection componenet and ubuntu package.

issue for ubuntu:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/symfony/+bug/1932552

symfony issue:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/8e34978e4e2c4bf7dac97e44e904368c4cfb54f8

phpmyadmin isseue stating they cannot do anything:https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16968#issuecomment-864088274

Tldr:
Try udpating your dependecies, possiblity changing repositories in ubnutu or wait until fix is distributed.

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

You can also downgrade your phpmyadmin version (not sure if it will help as it can be tied to php8.0 version)

Comment: Thank you, I tried to update dependencies but it did not work. I read issues you linked and one (symfony issue) was what I needed so I will describe solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

in nginx settings file switch php version from
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
on the
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).